# Install go scenery - cannot use &SceneryDefinition

Tags: go

I've got go installed. However, when I do this:

```
go get -u github.com/dmlittle/scenery
```

I get:

```
# github.com/dmlittle/scenery/pkg/parser
go/src/github.com/dmlittle/scenery/pkg/parser/parser.go:98:20: cannot use &SceneryDefinition literal (type *SceneryDefinition) as type lexer.Definition in argument to participle.Lexer:
    *SceneryDefinition does not implement lexer.Definition (wrong type for Lex method)
        have Lex(io.Reader) (lexer.Lexer, error)
        want Lex(string, io.Reader) (lexer.Lexer, error)
go/src/github.com/dmlittle/scenery/pkg/parser/parser.go:116:21: not enough arguments in call to p.ParseString
    have (string, *Plan)
    want (string, string, interface {}, ...participle.ParseOption)
go/src/github.com/dmlittle/scenery/pkg/parser/scanner.go:39:10: undefined: lexer.Errorf
go/src/github.com/dmlittle/scenery/pkg/parser/scanner.go:82:26: undefined: lexer.Errorf
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: That package does not appear to build as defined. Are you asking how to update that package's code, or how to implement some dependency management (which should be using go modules)?

Comment: Seems related to https://github.com/dmlittle/scenery/issues/42 also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same issue, seems the prj use dep. I've fixed cloning the repo, then configuring the go module that find the right project dependencies. Then run go get again and the build success:

```
~/go/src/github.com/dmlittle/scenery (master ✔) ᐅ go run main.go
# github.com/dmlittle/scenery/pkg/parser
pkg/parser/parser.go:98:20: cannot use &SceneryDefinition literal (type *SceneryDefinition) as type lexer.Definition in argument to participle.Lexer:
    *SceneryDefinition does not implement lexer.Definition (wrong type for Lex method)
        have Lex(io.Reader) (lexer.Lexer, error)
        want Lex(string, io.Reader) (lexer.Lexer, error)
pkg/parser/parser.go:116:21: not enough arguments in call to p.ParseString
    have (string, *Plan)
    want (string, string, interface {}, ...participle.ParseOption)
pkg/parser/scanner.go:39:10: undefined: lexer.Errorf
pkg/parser/scanner.go:82:26: undefined: lexer.Errorf
```

Init go mod:

```
~/go/src/github.com/dmlittle/scenery (master ✔) ᐅ go mod init
go: creating new go.mod: module github.com/dmlittle/scenery
go: copying requirements from Gopkg.lock
```

Check dependencies:

```
go mod tidy
go: downloading github.com/spf13/cobra v0.0.3
go: downloading github.com/fatih/color v1.7.0
....
```

Install package:

```
go get -u github.com/dmlittle/scenery
```

Works as expected :

```
~/go/src/github.com/dmlittle/scenery (master ✘)✭ ᐅ ./scenery
Usage:
  scenery [flags]

Examples:
  terraform plan | scenery

Flags:
  -h, --help       help for scenery
  -n, --no-color   Print output without color
      --version    version for scenery
```